# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript

function getSerialOverride() 
{

xdl_read_config("xdl_serialports_onboard_override",

function(response) {processSerialOverrideResponse(response);},

function(xhr, status, error)
            );
}

Comment: I know that JavaScript errors are not always super helpful. But it should be obvious that either you had a `)` to many, or it was preceded by an expression which could not be interpreted. That should usually be solvable without posting a question here. EDIT: In this case your last function declaration is also not complete but pointing that out is neither the purpose of this site. Good luck with getting better at JavaScript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ithink you just forgot the { } for the last function:

```
function getSerialOverride() {
    xdl_read_config(
        "xdl_serialports_onboard_override",
        function(response){processSerialOverrideResponse(response);},
        function(xhr, status, error){}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function(xhr, status, error) )
                        //  ^ where's the body of this function?
```

Comment: Thanks, Jaromanda X, I am actually very new to javascript , hopefully trying to get better.